# Why does this reductio ad absurdum work?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

A is something which we do not know the truth value of, for example:
A = It will rain tomorrow.
It might happen, it might not. So possibly A is true, and possibly ~A is also true.
What is wrong with the below reductio ad absurdum?
Where I will take A as the assumed premise, show that it leads to a contradiction and then assert the negation of A as the conclusion.

Assume A.
Possibly ~A (which we know is true).
A & possibly ~A is a contradiction.
Therefore ~A.
If this works, I have proved that it will not rain tomorrow...which of course cannot be...so where does the problem lie? If we assume A, can we not say 'possibly ~A'? (I looked at some modal logic....but I don't think possibly ~A is the same as '~A is true in some possible world'.)
Thanks very much guys

Comment: "**A** and possibly **not-A**" is not a contradiciton. A contradicition is "**A** and **not-A**.

Comment: If A is true, how can it be possible that ~A? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: According to the (more-or-less) precise definition of *possible* in modern modal logic, "possibly **A**" means: "there is a world, maybe different from the current one, where **A** holds".

Comment: There is **NO** way to prove "by logic" that it is raining (or not). This is an empirical fact and no empirical facts can be known without the "resources" of experience.

Comment: Regarding your similar previous question, **NO** logical proof can prove the existence (or not) of God. Every proof needs some preliminary assumptions (as well as the rules of logic): in math they are called *axioms* and we have to assume them as TRUE in order to assert the claim that what we have proved from them is TRUE. Thus, in order to assert that "God exists" is TRUE on the ground of some proof, you have to state precisely what "axioms" you are assuming as TRUE, and argue on what ground the purported axioms are to be considered TRUE.

Comment: Thanks Mauro, and if I assert A, is this translated into modal logic as 'A is true in the actual world' (might be necessary, might not be)?

Comment: Yep I am aware of what you wrote about empircal facts and needing axioms to prove God, I am just trying to show why an argument for God doesn't work. I want to say *exactly* why it doesn't work, not vaguely. So, any thoughts on how A can be true, but also its true that possibly not A?

Comment: According to *modal logic*, "possibly **not-A**" is the same as "not-necessarily **A**". The semantics of "necessarily **A**" is: "in **every** possible world **A** holds". Thus, the semantics of "not-necessarily **A**" is: "**there is** a possible world where **A** does not hold". Thus, in this world it rains but in some other world "out there" in the multiverse of possibilities it does not.

Comment: Think of "Possibly not-A" as "A or not A".  Then your formulation becomes "1) A, and 2) A or not A" which has no contradiction.

Comment: I would have thought A and possibly ~A would imply that 'possibly (A &~A)', that's seems to be what the words would imply. Also, what if I changed the statement to 'A is true and ~A can also be true' that would be false, ~A cannot be true?

Comment: You would need a distribution notion like possibly A and possible not A implies possibly A and not A.  But that is obviously false, possibly my Lab is yellow and possibly my Lab is black does not mean that possibly my Lab is both yellow and black -- they are monochrome dogs.  This kind of distribution is true of 'box-like' modalities like necessity and false of their duals.

Comment: And there is no conflict in the idea that A is true and *might* be false.  You are both playing win tenses in an unwarranted way and swapping modals.  I might be 7 foot tall, given a different history, but I am 6 foot tall and I cannot be 7 foot tall.

Comment: Not only is the distribution rule wrong, your first step also fails.  it is not true for every A that we do not know the truth or falsity of that it might be untrue.  Some values of A are necessarily true.  A could be something logically tautological that you have just not understood yet.  So we do not know that given any A of the sort you consider, possibly ~A.  Possibly ~A is true before A is chosen, but once A is chosen, it is no longer known.  And your first step is to choose A.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, "Possibly A and possibly not-A" is not a contradiction. But "A and possibly not-A" is. Of course, if we do not count all dependencies. "There definitely will rain tomorrow. Probably it's not the case."

Answer (score 2):

A and possibly not-A are not contradictory in modal logic.

In your question, you use epistemic possibilities: what is possible or not given our current knowledge. Now A could be the case while it would still be possible, according to our limited knowledge, that not-A, so A and possibly not-A are not contradictory.

You seem to mean by "let us assume A" that we would know that A is the case. Then of course it will be contradictory, but this should be expressed in modal logic by "necessarily A" which is indeed contradictory with "possibly not-A".
If you had assumed, say, nomological possibilities, whether something is possible according to the laws of nature, there would be no contradiction either: "tomorrow it will rain" could be true while at the same time, "tomorrow it will not rain" could also conform to the laws of nature.

However, there's indeed a paradox with knowledge, called Fitch's paradox, which more or less resembles yours. You might be interested in that:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitch's_paradox_of_knowability

Also related is Aristotle's discussion on fatalism:
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/fatalism/#1

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65410/discussion-on-answer-by-quentin-ruyant-why-does-this-reductio-ad-absurdum-work).

Answer (score 1):

Even without involving possible-world semantics, this is just an equivocation. English is really bad about the locations of negations in modal constructions.

Worst case: "You may not do that" means two completely different things depending upon the timing of the delivery -- 1) that you are not allowed, or 2) that you cannot be expected -- to 'do that'.

You need something more rigid to separate the ideas that A might possibly have be false, and that it is false that A might possibly have been true. Once you separate those, it is kind of clear that there is no contradiction with the idea that A might possibly have been false, even when it is true.

From one philological take, there is a good reason that English subjunctives expressing possibilities use 'would', 'should' or 'might', the past tenses of the words 'will', 'shall' and 'may', which express different conditions on predicting the future (for instance, doing so certainly, certainly if proper social rules are followed, or uncertainly).  Possibility is not a state of reality, it is the potential future of a past state of reality.  And even when used of the present, it is implicitly future perfect in tense.

In that sense, there is no way in which you can have both possibility and eternality in the same epistemology.  If anyone can predict the future, things are possible only if they happen.

Comment: Thanks for your response, if I don't know something, does that mean that 'it  might possibly have been false' ?

Comment: That depends on what kind of thing it is, and that falls back on your basic ontology.  By standard notions of logic, to the degree that the law of contradiction is now true, it is not true that it might possibly have been false.  In the framing taken here, possibility is about prediction, which includes a theory of causation, and comes in flavors that go along with different standards of prediction.

Comment: In the same way, the 'should' modality depends upon a theory of ethics or politics, etc.  And the 'could' modality depends upon a physics.  Modalities apply theories to alternative facts.  Otherwise, there is no point in having modality at all.  You should just say what you do and do not know.